# How do I resize a map with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I'm trying to build my first simple Android application that displays the VesselFinder map from its website, but I'm having issues resizing it. When I open the url in my phone's browser the map almost fills up the entire screen, however, the WebView in my app (which has a titlebar) displays it with a much smaller height.

[WebView with map loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CQqh.png)

So I tried resizing it with JavaScript like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('map').style.height='92vh'; " +
                "})()");
```

Where 'map' is the div Id the map is in (alternative would be div class 'map-container'). Unfortunately it stretches out the map and makes it harder to use.

[WebView with resized map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5WS9.png)

Is there a way I could fix this? I'm guessing I should trigger a map resize but don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: if you already try to do this with javascript, why do you set only height to 92vh, but not width to same 92vh?

Comment: Width is already showing correctly, I only need to fill up the empty space below the map. If I change the width to keep the ratio I loose map's control buttons as they get pushed out of the screen.